# Get NoSuchElementException if test data have only single record which is of unseen label

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using NaiveBayes multinomial classifier in Apache Spark ML (version 2.1.0) to predict some text categories.

Using StringIndexer for transforming string to label like as below:

```
    val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("name").setOutputCol("label").fit(trainData).setHandleInvalid("skip")
```

It is giving an exception while prediction on testing data have only single record which is of unseen label. if there are combination of seen and unseen label then its work fine and it will skip that unseen label record in prediction result.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:64)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:91)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$head(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.head(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:120)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.head(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1943)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.first(Dataset.scala:1950)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.first$lzycompute$1(VectorAssembler.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.org$apache$spark$ml$feature$VectorAssembler$$first$1(VectorAssembler.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1.apply$mcI$sp(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:58)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transform(VectorAssembler.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(Pipeline.scala:299)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(Pipeline.scala:299)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.transform(Pipeline.scala:299)
at com.infostretch.machinelearning.sample.GroupingByNaiveBayesExample$.main(GroupingByNaiveBayesExample.scala:111)
at com.infostretch.machinelearning.sample.GroupingByNaiveBayesExample.main(GroupingByNaiveBayesExample.scala)
```

**Training Data :**

`id,group,name,text
1,apple,abc,a b c d
2,orange,def,x y z`

**Test Data:**

`id,name,text
3,pqr,a b x`

Here, field name value 'pqr' is unseen for model while do prediction on test data.

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by seen and unseen label?

Comment: I have total 4 fields id,group(which is used for prediction label),name,text for training data based on two field(name & text) i do prediction of group.
and for name field i used StringIndexer. and text i have used Tokenizer.

TrainingData:
`id,group,name,text
1,apple,abc,a b c d
2,orange,def,x y`

Test data:
`id,name,text
3,pqr,a b x
4,abc,d a b`

Here, 'abc' is seen and 'pqr' is unseen because it is not there in training data for field name.